# Mac Cron Job Failed : Sh Script runs fine manually, fails to fetch git origin in crontab

Tags: git, macos, cron

When I execute command  to fetch my bitbucket repository, it works fine

When I set up command in crontab to fetch my bitbucket repository, it does not work and provide me this message

```
Fetching origin
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://jacksonRaju124@bitbucket.org': Device not configured
error: Could not fetch origin
```

Would you please tell me what settings on repository credential login (App Password/ SSH Key) would solve this login problem? What other git config do I need to set to allow automated **`git pull`** ?

Below is my script:

```
cd ios_app_proj/src && git fetch --all && git checkout master
```

Comment: macOS has its own methods for allowing programs to access keys, and I haven't delved into these, but in general, you should use an `ssh://` URL, not an `https://` URL, so that Git will invoke ssh, and ssh can use whatever kinds of access are made available by the system. I added the [tag:macos] tag so that you can get macOS-specific answers.

Comment: And make sure the user the cron call is made as has the key for your repo